# Route using wrong validator in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Postman to test the routes and this route returns the err message after `user.save((err)=>{})` saying that the password is too long. It uses a `passwordValidator` I created but I obviously didn't call it for this route neither in Schema.

What am I doing wrong?

The user schema in mongoose:

```
    const userSchema=new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: emailValidators},
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true, validate: usernameValidators},
    bio: { type:String,default:null,validate:bioValidators},
    location: {type:String, default:null},
    gender: {type:String,default:null,validate:genderValidators},
    birthday: { type:String,default:null},
    password: { type: String, required: true,validate: passwordValidators}
});
```

The route:

```
router.put('/editProfile',(req,res)=>{
        if(!req.body.bio){
            res.json({success:false,message:"No bio provided"});
        }
        else{
            if(!req.body.location){
                res.json({success:false,message:"No location provided"});
            }
            else{
                if(!req.body.gender){
                    res.json({success:false,message:"No gender provided"});
                }
                else{
                    if (!req.body.birthday) {
                        res.json({success:false,message:"No birthday provided"});
                    }
                    else{
                        User.findOne({_id:req.decoded.userId},(err,user)=>{
                            if(err){
                                res.json({success:false,message:"Something went wrong: "+err});
                            }
                            else{
                                if(!user){
                                    res.json({success:false,message:"User not found"});
                                }
                                else{
                                    user.bio=req.body.bio;
                                    user.location=req.body.location;
                                    user.gender=req.body.gender;
                                    user.birthday=req.body.birthday;
                                    user.save((err)=>{
                                        if(err){
                                            res.json({success:false,message:'Something went wrong: '+ err}); //returns this
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            res.json({success:true,message:"Account updated !"});
                                        }
                                    }); 
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

Here's the password validator array

```
const passwordValidators = [
    {
        validator: passwordLengthChecker,
        message: 'Password must be at least 5 characters but no more than 40'
    },
    {
        validator:validPassword,
        message: 'Must have at least one uppercase, lowercase, special character, and number'
    }
];
```

and the checkers

```
let passwordLengthChecker = (password)=>{
    if (!password) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if(password.length<5 || password.length>40){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
};

let validPassword = (password)=>{
    if (!password) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        const regExp = new RegExp(/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[\d])(?=.*?[\W]).{8,35}$/);
        return regExp.test(password);
    }
};
```

As you can see it's using the passwordLengthChecker though it shouldn't

**EDIT N°2**

I just realized i have this middleware just below the schema

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    if(!this.isModified('password'))
    return next();

    bcrypt.hash(this.password, null, null, (err,hash)=>{
        if(err) return next(err);
        this.password=hash;
        next();
    });
});
```

does it mean this function is gonna run everytime I use save() ?

Comment: `validate: passwordValidators` isn't this the problem? what are you using for passwordValidators? can you show us?

Comment: here's the validator

Comment: please check the answer. you are forgetting to provide a password for the user @Azoulay Jason

Comment: please let me know if you were able to do it with the new update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down here is the problem, you providing `bio` , `location`, `gender`, `birthday` but not password. When you do not declare a password its `length` will be equal to `0`. That's why you get error back. Length can be from `5` to `40`.

```
else{
                                    user.password=req.body.password;
                                    //I added user.password here, this is what you should do
                                    user.bio=req.body.bio;
                                    user.location=req.body.location;
                                    user.gender=req.body.gender;
                                    user.birthday=req.body.birthday;
                                    user.save((err)=>{
                                        if(err){
                                            res.json({success:false,message:'Something went wrong: '+ err}); //returns this
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            res.json({success:true,message:"Account updated !"});
                                        }
                                    }); 
                                }
```

**UPDATE HERE**

If you are only going to update `bio`,`location`,`gender` and `birthday` then using `save()` function is wrong. You need to use `findOneAndUpdate()` function.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.decoded.userId}, { $rename : {gender: 'male' , bio : 'somethingElse'}}, {new: true}, function(err, user){
if(err) throw err;
else{
console.log("done : " + user.gender);
}
});
```

Also please see  [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)  and  [its operators to be used](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I thougt at first so i tried this solution, But since the password is encrypted it cannot fit to passwordValidators.
I think the real problem here is that it runs every validators and i don't find the solution to get around this issue

Comment: @AzoulayJason Then you need to change the configurations, you need to check the length before it gets encrypted!

Comment: in the back end server right after the `post` request, check the length  of the **user input** `req.body.password` first, then do the progress. Your configuration is wrong @AzoulayJason

Comment: Yes but at this stage, I cannot get the current user's unencrypted password unless i ask him again !  I have to find the way to run the correct validators, i've seen about synchronous mongoose validators, this is probably the solution

Comment: isn't this an profile edit page that I get from => `/editProfile`. is this a page to change passwords? if so please check **user input** before implementing the text into the database

Comment: This page only has to update bio,location,gender and birthday on the database, datas which are supposed to be null at registration.

Comment: @AzoulayJason I have updated the answer, you can't use `save` here, instead you will update the info you have with `findOneAndUpdate()` so you have nothing to do with password. also always use that function for updates to a single user.

Answer (score 0):

So i think the bcrypt function compromised the Mongoose save() function, 
i found an other solution for now in Mongoose doc.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.decoded.userId,{$set:{bio:req.body.bio, location:req.body.location, gender:req.body.gender, birthday:req.body.birthday}},{new:true},function(err,user){
                            if(err){
                                res.json({success:false,message:"Something went wrong: "+err});
                            }
                            else{
                                if(!user){
                                    res.json({success:false,message:"User not found"});
                                }
                                else{
                                    res.json({success:true,user:user});
                                }
                            }
                        });
```